# Passing Pointers to Pointers into Functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I'm working on a class project and I'm still learning C.

The goal is to ask the user how many items are available for sale today, and then ask them to enter those items one-by-one to new lines, and have them be entered into an array of strings.

Then print the array as a list to show the available items.

We cannot use statically declared arrays, and must use only pointers.

The functions here are required. I am required to have the get_items() function modify the array rather than return a result.

I'm having a lot of trouble making get_items() work. Anything I try either ends up with "exited, segmentation fault" or printing (NULL) when I go to print the items of the array.

Any suggestions to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

```
char* get_item() {

  char *item = calloc(61,sizeof(char));
  scanf(" %[^\n]",item);

  return item;

}
```

```
void get_items(char ***items, int *num_items){

  int i;

    printf("Enter the %d available items one to a line: \n",*num_items);


  for(i = 0; i < *num_items; i++) {

    **(items+i) = get_item();

  }

}
```

```
int main(void) {

  char **items=NULL;    /* this is the pointer for the start of the ingredients array   */
  int num_items = -1,
  int i;

  printf("How many available items do we have today? ");
  scanf("%d",&num_items);

  items = calloc(num_items,sizeof(char*));

  get_items(&items,&num_items);

  printf("Available items today are: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {

    printf("%i. %s\n",i+1,*(items+i));

  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need more than two asterisks.  `char**` is an array of strings.

Comment: `void get_items(...)` <<-- why does it return void, instead of the result?

Comment: @wildplasser: Because it is modifying the array in place.

Comment: Which is not needed, the calloc() could be done in get_items().

Comment: Aside: There is no point using `int *` for the second parameter (`num_items`) of `get_items`. Just use `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In `get_items`, `**(items+i)` should be `*(*items+i)` or `(*items)[i]`.

However, `get_items` has too many levels of pointer dereferencing. The following is simpler:

```
void get_items(char **items, int num_items){

  int i;

    printf("Enter the %d available items one to a line: \n",num_items);


  for(i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {

    *(items+i) = get_item();  // or more readable: items[i] = get_item();

  }

}
```

The call to `get_items` from `main` would then need to be changed to the following:

```
  get_items(items,num_items);
```

---

The original prototype `void get_items(char ***items, int *num_items)` suggests that some of the code in `main` should have been done in `get_items` instead:

```
void get_items(char ***items, int *num_items){
    int i;

    printf("How many available items do we have today? ");
    scanf("%d",num_items);

    *items = calloc(*num_items,sizeof(char*));

    printf("Enter the %d available items one to a line: \n",*num_items);

    for(i = 0; i < *num_items; i++) {
        *(*items+i) = get_item();
    }
}
```

Then `main` can be reduced to the following:

```
int main(void) {

    char **items=NULL;    /* this is the pointer for the start of the ingredients array   */
    int num_items = -1,
    int i;

    get_items(&items,&num_items);

    printf("Available items today are: \n");

    for(i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        printf("%i. %s\n",i+1,*(items+i));
    }
}
```